# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class under ROOT in TOMCAT 7

Tags: tomcat7

I am starting off with Tomcat and this is my first exercise.  I created a TestServlet and placed it under C:\tomcat-7.0.34\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes.  The important thing is, this is working on one computer but not in the other.  I have verified that the classpath and path are correct.  If I remove the TestServlet.class file (placed under the classes directory), tomcat gives error when starting up.  If not, it is ok.  This means that based on the web.xml file, the servelet is loaded?  If so when I invoke it as "localhost:8080/TestServlet", why does it give HTTP 500 error.`

My web.xml file under WEB-INF is as follows:

```
<display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
<description>
    Welcome to Tomcat
</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>TestServlet2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My TestServlet code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {...
```

I am so frustrated - spent almost 8 hrs in trying to resolve this issue..

Help will be much appreciated..

Full Trace:
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    Feb 09, 2016 11:58:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    Feb 09, 2016 11:58:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener:     attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@71ccdf3d')
    Feb 09, 2016 11:58:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Marking servlet TestServlet as unavailable
    Feb 09, 2016 11:58:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve   invoke
    SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet TestServlet
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sorry, finally, I found the issue.. for some reason the "classes" directory was with the cap "Classes".  Once I renamed it, it worked!!

Comment: can you better describe the differences between the two environments? Also, your use of "ROOT" - we are to assume under the user `root` or just that its right off of your localhost's `root path` ?

Comment: The difference is, I had downloaded a pre-configured version "tomcat-7.0.34-preconfigured.zip" on one computer but this version when I downloaded on my work computer was giving too many errors - so I downloaded -  "tomcat-7.0.34-windows-x64.zip".  Both are windows 64 machines.  ROOT referes to tomcat..\webapps\ROOT

Comment: Could you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: thanks for your respose!!  Here's the full trace logon localhost;

Comment: sorry, gives an error that the comment is too long

Comment: According to the logs - `TestServlet` is not on the classpath.

Comment: @Brandt & fateddy -sorry, for wasting your time...  it was because of the folder name "Classes" under WEB-INF